# Replacing the value of HTML parameter dynamically

Tags: android, html, webview, flash

I am not sure if the title clearly states my difficulty here but I wanted to keep the title short. Anyway I am working on a project in android where in am displaying flash files in a WebView. The code is simple but repetitive. that's the reason why i want to cut the repetitive portion. I have an activity which displays text and gives an option of a play button if there is a swf file associated with that particular text. Once i hit play button swf file plays. Now there are many swf files and many text pages. I don't want to write 'n' activities for 'n' files and swf animations. So in the code below you will see a file a.swf. i want to change that particular value with b.swf,c.swf and so on. How can i do that? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    package com.example.testflashfile;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class PlayAnimationActivity extends Activity 
{
    WebView presentationWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        setContentView(R.layout.animation_one);

        String html =
                "<object><embed src=\"file:///android_asset/a.swf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" max-width=\"100%\"> </embed> </object>";
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.presentation_webview);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding,  "");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());




    }

    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the part that is going to be changed when user makes a selection

```
String html = "<object><embed src=\"file:///android_asset/a.swf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" max-width=\"100%\"> </embed> </object>";
```

You gonna have to write a new method that will receive the user selection and will return a string that is relevant to the selection

```
public String getMyHTMLString(String userSelection){
 String htmlString = "<object><embed src=\"file:///android_asset/"+userSelection+".swf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" max-width=\"100%\"> </embed> </object>";
 return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: i am getting the name of the swf file from another activity(the activity which plays this activity) how can i send swf file name via intent? what should be in the putExtra method? for say the file name is b.swf

Comment: Yes you can pass data as strings with intents. Read this http://android.mayuonline.com/2011/05/20/passing-data-with-intent/